# TFS - Is branching a project means copy of a project?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I learn a lot but I can't understand what does branching do?

I have a project in TFS and want to copy it and change in it. Can I use branching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a copy of the project.

Lets say you are working on a big project and you do a deployment to a customer. You take that version and branch it.

Whenever you need to fix any bugs you can do that in the branche and merge it into your main project again.

All future development can be done in the main version without affecting the version with your customer.

But in your case if it is just to make a copy for some modifications for yourself, or for testing. You can do a copy on folder level.

Comment: Just a clarification about using the word "copy". While it is logically correct, be aware the actual files/items are not copied on the server, but point to the parent until they are changed. So a branch only takes up a small amount of data on the server.